# I write axios post method in React and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin but request is not working and response to me cors origin error

Tags: python, reactjs, cors, xmlhttprequest, axios

## I write axios post method in React and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin but the request is not working and send this response:

#### Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.aaaa.com/aaa/login/' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
axios.post('https://api.aaa.com/aaa/login/', userlogin , {
            headers :{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://api.aaa.com',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            }
        })
```

In Backend Code (Django), I add corsheaders Package and CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://0.0.0.0:3000/']

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Change http://api.aaa.com to *

Comment: on api side add header as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 1):

> CROS has to be added from webservice , for example if the api(https://api.aaaa.com/aaa/login/) is
>   written in php then in php script add below headers  :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
```

> For Django:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3030',
)
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3030',
)
```